# how to provide print option to my form inC#.net

Tags: c#-4.0

in my project i have one registration form which is developed in C#.net.to this form at lost i have an print button on clicking this button i have to get print window which we usually see when we give print in our system .plz provide me this code and help me. thanks uu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try a  PrintDailog ,    

  // Declare the PrintDocument object.
private System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument docToPrint = 
    new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();

// This method will set properties on the PrintDialog object and
// then display the dialog.
private void Button1_Click(System.Object sender, 
    System.EventArgs e)
{

    // Allow the user to choose the page range he or she would
    // like to print.
    PrintDialog1.AllowSomePages = true;

    // Show the help button.
    PrintDialog1.ShowHelp = true;

    // Set the Document property to the PrintDocument for 
    // which the PrintPage Event has been handled. To display the
    // dialog, either this property or the PrinterSettings property 
    // must be set 
    PrintDialog1.Document = docToPrint;

    DialogResult result = PrintDialog1.ShowDialog();

    // If the result is OK then print the document.
    if (result==DialogResult.OK)
    {
        docToPrint.Print();
    }

}

// The PrintDialog will print the document
// by handling the document's PrintPage event.
private void document_PrintPage(object sender, 
    System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{

    // Insert code to render the page here.
    // This code will be called when the control is drawn.

    // The following code will render a simple
    // message on the printed document.
    string text = "In document_PrintPage method.";
    System.Drawing.Font printFont = new System.Drawing.Font
        ("Arial", 35, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular);

    // Draw the content.
    e.Graphics.DrawString(text, printFont, 
        System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, 10, 10);
}
```

source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.printdialog.aspx